# Error getting array value by key

Tags: php

This is a very strange one.

I'm making a request with the following code.

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Bearer: 5AE3lc//bq+k+M2M+tuGxW4K4K8=:i3kHKXStNXs9FnAg/IgWPNHYFBo=\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = fopen($csvFile, 'r', false, $context);
```

In the script receiving the request I have this:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
var_dump($headers['Bearer']); // I get Undefined index: Bearer
$headers = json_decode(json_encode($headers), true);
var_dump($headers['Bearer']); //this one works.
```

But var_dump of $headers array looks the same before or after encode and decode.

```
//first var_dump
    array(4) {
      ["Host"]=>
      string(19) "" //removed
      ["Accept-Language"]=>
      string(2) "en"
      ["Bearer"]=>
      string(57) "5AE3lc//bq+k+M2M+tuGxW4K4K8=:i3kHKXStNXs9FnAg/IgWPNHYFBo="
      ["Cookie"]=>
      string(7) "foo=bar"
    }
//second var_dump, after decode/encode
    array(4) {
      ["Host"]=>
      string(19) "" //removed
      ["Accept-Language"]=>
      string(2) "en"
      ["Bearer"]=>
      string(57) "5AE3lc//bq+k+M2M+tuGxW4K4K8=:i3kHKXStNXs9FnAg/IgWPNHYFBo="
      ["Cookie"]=>
      string(7) "foo=bar"
    }
```

The "Bearer" key is the only one I can't access from the beginning. I can get the others without any problem.

var_dump for array_keys of $headers

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Host"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "Connection"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "User-Agent"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Bearer"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Accept"
  [5]=>
  string(15) "Accept-Encoding"
  [6]=>
  string(15) "Accept-Language"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "Cookie"
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `var_dump($headers)` please.

Comment: updated with $headers var_dump

Comment: I doesn't really make any sense at all why it would behave that way.

Comment: What version of PHP ? Out of interest are you using WAMP ?

Comment: Can you add that header : "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"

Comment: @hurricane I added this header and results are the same.

Comment: @exussum I'm making the request from nginx + php, and receiving it on apache+php

Comment: is the receiving end using WAMP ?

Comment: Do you have a filter on your second server? (etc F5, Apache Conf.). Maybe it doesn't allow to send headers.

Comment: Just tried on my local server and both 'var_dump' return the same value, so it may be something with your server configuration.

Comment: the receiving is a cpanel server on a shared host. It reads headers so this is not the issue. The "Bearer" key is the only one I can't access. I can get the others without any problem.

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` `array_keys` for `$headers` as well?

Comment: @AlexandruRada, is "Bearer" key thet same in both arrays (before and after encode/decode)? Especially its length. Maybe there's unprintable character in the first array.

Comment: does the behaviour change if you specify the `$header` array manually instead of `$headers = getallheaders();`?

Comment: @AlexandruRada try your header string with `PHP_EOL` instead of `\r\n` and see if that makes a difference. Alternatively, look at the source of `json_encode` and `json_decode` for clues as that obviously does what you're missing. :)

Answer (score 0):

`/`, `=`, and `:` are separator characters in HTTP headers. Try encoding the value for Bearer when defining `$opts`

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Bearer: " . urlencode('5AE3lc//bq+k+M2M+tuGxW4K4K8=:i3kHKXStNXs9FnAg/IgWPNHYFBo=') . "\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
    )
);
```